# Methodes in Constructor repeats

Tags: c#

I want the "BombenGenerieren(anzahlMinen)" only one time, how should I write it, that it doesn't generates new bombs every round?

```
public Game(int anzahlMinen, int xeingabe, int yeingabe)
{
  _minenArray = new int[5, 5];
  _emptyArray = new int[5, 5];
  _boolArray = new bool[5, 5];
  program = new Program();
  zeichnen = new Draw();

  BombenGenerieren(anzahlMinen);
  FillPlayMap();
  Umdreher(yeingabe, xeingabe);
  zeichnen.OpenField(_minenArray, _boolArray);
  //SeenMap();

}
```

Comment: I think some more context is needed. How is this object used? When is the constructor called?

Comment: Just define a `bool` and set it to `false` after you did it the first time. Afterwards only execute `BombenGenerieren` if that `bool` is true.

Comment: I believe we're looking at a constructor here, so the proposed boolean would just be initilized to `false` each time.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. The constructor is only run once, anyway, so why would is be useful to check if has run already?

Comment: @Rik, you're right. the core problem is that a `new Game()` is invoked for 'every round'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `Game` is a constructor and you want to execute `BombenGenerieren` once and share it between instances.

What you should do, is make `BombenGenerieren` static and store whatever the effect of `BombenGenerieren` is in one or more static fields or properties. You should then call `Game.BombenGenerieren` before instantiating new `Game` objects, or alternatively create a static constructor as follows:

```
public static Game()
{
    BombenGenerieren(anzahlMinen);
}
```

The static constructor will be executed the first time you use the `Game` type. Note that it does no take parameters, so anzahlMinen will have to be a constant. If that is a problem, go with the regular static method.

Another alternative is to encapsulate the result of the `BombenGenerieren` method in an object and pass that to the `Game` constructor, whcih can apply the result to each new class.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, utilize a `boolean` variable to keep track of the execution of `BombenGenerieren`.

```
boolean bombenGeneriert = false;

public Game(int anzahlMinen, int xeingabe, int yeingabe) {
    //...

    BombenGenerieren(anzahlMinen);

    //...
}

public void BombenGenerieren(int minen) {
    if (!bombenGeneriert) {
        bombenGeneriert = true;

        //the rest of your code in this method
    }
}
```

This will set `bombenGeneriert` to true the first the method is executed. Now on every execution it checks for `!bombenGeneriert` which will evaluate to `false`.

Besides, you should consider rearranging your code. I suspect you call `Game()` more than once, so you should probably relocate your `BombenGenerieren()` method, somewhere outside `Game()`.

If `Game` is your **class** and `Game()` a **constructor**, than `bombenGeneriert` hast to be static:

```
static boolean bombenGeneriert = false;
```

Comment: `bombenGeneriert` needs to be `static`.

Comment: Just read the comments to the question. It only has to be static, if `Game` really is a constructor.

Comment: If `bombenGeneriert` is static, then whatever the result of `BombenGenerieren` is, should also be preserved outside of the current instance, somehow.